# env->FindClass does not work in another thread

Tags: java, android, c++, juce

If I alter Juce's `JNI_Onload` to this:

```cpp
extern "C" jint JNIEXPORT JNI_OnLoad (JavaVM* vm, void*)
{
    // Huh? JNI_OnLoad was called two times!
    jassert (androidJNIJavaVM == nullptr);

    androidJNIJavaVM = vm;

    auto* env = getEnv();

    // register the initialisation function
    auto juceJavaClass = env->FindClass("com/rmsl/juce/Java");
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Tag", "finding MainActivity");
    auto S = env->FindClass("com/my_app/flutter_app/MainActivity");
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Tag", "finding MainActivity END");
    if (!S) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "finding MainActivity END");
    } else {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Tag", "DID find MainActivity");
    }
```

It works without any problem. That is, the class `MainActivity` is found.

However, this line:

```cpp
auto mainActivityClass1 = env->FindClass("com/my_app/flutter_app/MainActivity");
```

called in this code:

```cpp
MyJuceApp() {
    JNIEnv* env = juce::getEnv();
    auto mainActivityClass1 = env->FindClass("com/my_app/flutter_app/MainActivity");
```

Where `START_JUCE_APPLICATION (MyJuceApp)` gives an error:

```
A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:523] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallBooleanMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.my_app.flutter_app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "InMemoryDexFile[cookie=[0, 547943543104]]"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
```

It looks like when `JNI_Onload()` is called, it's called from the Java thread. Then, `JNI_Onload()` calls some Juce internal things that starts the app by calling `MyJuceApp`, where things fail. I think it fails because `MyJuceApp` is initialized from another thread.

So, the class definitely exists, because `JNI_Onload` finds it. But when `MyJuceApp` constructor is called, it cannot find the same class anymore.

I also tried attaching the thread:

```cpp
JNIEnv* env = juce::getEnv();
JavaVM* vm;
env->GetJavaVM(&vm);
JavaVMAttachArgs args;
args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
args.name = nullptr;
args.group = nullptr;
JNIEnv* env2 = juce::getEnv();
vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env2, &args);
auto mainActivityClass1 = env2->FindClass("com/my_app/flutter_app/MainActivity");
```

and got the same problem.

PS: `env->FindClass("java/lang/String")` works, where `env->FindClass("com/my_app/flutter_app/MainActivity")` does not, which makes things even more confusing. But the class name is correct, because it's found in `JNI_Onload()`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#faq_FindClass

Answer (score 0):

Last year When I was investigating the same issue, I wrote a lengthy blog post on how I identified and fixed the issue at https://atsushieno.github.io/2022/03/16/juce-android-threads.html

Looks like this SO question identical to the JUCE forum post that I mentioned on my blog post.